# How did Gilgamesh die?

Tags: gilgamesh, sumerian, mesopotamia

Do we know how and in which circumstances Gilgamesh died?

According to [these answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120209235546AANK73n) seems that The Epic of Gilgamesh doesn't mention that, however [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh) mention something about Sumerian poem - The Death of Gilgamesh.

Comment: Translations of various versions of The Death of Gilgamesh: http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/section1/tr1813.htm

Comment: If it was common for some to live to 900 years + during that time, 126 years may have seemed young.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to **[The Electronic Text Corpus of Sumerian Literature](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/index1.htm)**, my best guess from reading the [translated text provided](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/section1/tr1813.htm) is he died of old age :

> ..... hero ...... has lain down and is never to rise again. ...... has lain down and is never to rise again. He of well-proportioned limbs ...... has lain down and is never to rise again. ...... has lain down and is never to rise again. He who ...... wickedness has lain down and is never to rise again. The young man ...... has lain down and is never to rise again. He who was perfect in ...... and feats of strength has lain down and is never to rise again. ......

It doesn't give an specific explanation for his death, but the text is fragmentary at best and several parts are missing.

Comment: If he died of old age, why the translation say: 'The young man ...... has lain down and is never to rise again.'?

Comment: On [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh#cite_ref-3) we can read 'According to the Sumerian King List, Gilgamesh ruled his city for 126 years.' so I think this suggests that he died of old age. However it's not for sure what kind of lifespan his kind had.

Comment: The text of segment B seems to point toward death from old age/disease as well:  `For six days, he ...... ill. ...... on his skin like resin. Lord Gilgamec ...... ill.`  Segment A and B both reference his death-bed as well, which at least implies he died in bed.  Including those might strengthen the answer, to my mind.

Comment: @kenorb Some of the kings mentioned in the list ruled for over 20,000 years. Gilgamesh is an infant in comparison.